# How can I change the default value of an HTML selection after a button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a selection in my code that looks like this:

```
<select id="currency">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="USD">USD</option>
  <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
  <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
</select>
```

The selected value will be displayed after a button click, and that works all well. But is there a way to, like, set the select value that's shown on the selection to the first option "Select" after the button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `selectedIndex`

```js
function changeSelection() {
  document.getElementById('currency').selectedIndex = 3
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="currency">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="USD">USD</option>
  <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
  <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
</select>
<button onclick='changeSelection()'>Change Selection</button>
```